# Can I acquire technologies through diplomacy even if I don't have the prerequisite?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-2

One of the AI opponents has 3 technologies I don't have: "Trade", "Advanced Trade" and "Master Trade".

Is it possible to get "Advanced Trade" and "Master Trade" even if I don't have "Trade" or will they only trade it with me if I also trade the prerequisite technologies in the same deal?

If it is possible to get technologies without fulfilling their requirements regarding earlier technologies, what consequences does this have for the tech tree?

Comment: It is possible to get later technologies without "explicitly" trading for the pre-requisites, but I don't recall the specifics...

Comment: Another option I thought of only later: Maybe you just implicitly get the previous techs in the deal as well?

Comment: That might apply to some techs, but not weapon techs for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get technologies without their prerequisites through technology trade.

The consequence for the tech tree: There will be holes (unresearched technologies).

This might or might not be of consequence, depending on your play style.

However, you will not get any bonus of the prerequisite technology. So if you're aiming for a specific bonus for that stage of tech, you still need to research it.

Comment: Confirmed empirically